# Palindrome function not working in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

the following is part of a much bigger program.

```
wordStr = open("words.txt",'rU')

def isPalindrome(wordStr):
    palindromeCount = 0
    for word in wordStr:
        if word == word[::-1]:
            palindromeCount += 1
    print palindromeCount

isPalindrome(wordStr)
```

words.txt contains thousands of words and it is in the same folder as the program. With this function I am trying to go through and count the number of words that are palindromes (spelled the same front and back) in the text file. It simply returns 0 every time and never even gets into the if statement and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Why are you using `rU` as the read mode?

Comment: @Blender, what should they be using?

Comment: Is there any reason not to open in rU mode? I assign wordStr to the text file that has all of the words. In that function if I add a counter that incriments by one between the for and if loop and print the counter at the end, it prints the number of words in the file. So wordStr clearly contains a bunch of words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for word in wordStr` will iterate over the **lines** in wordStr.  Probably each of your lines has an end-of-line marker, something like `\n`.  If you `print repr(word)`, you'll probably see it.

I would try

```
for word in wordStr:
    print repr(word)
    word = word.strip()
    [etc]
```

as a first pass.

Comment: Good call, I forgot about the newlines. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You need to strip extra newlines from the individual lines and have your function return a value:

```
wordFile = open("words.txt",'rU')

def PalindromeCount(wordFile):
    palindromeCount = 0
    for word in wordFile:
        word = word.strip()
        if word == word[::-1]:
            palindromeCount += 1
    return palindromeCount
```

When I run it on this data:

```
meatloaf
radar
ardra
fish
```

I get this result:  `2`

Comment: Your first problem isn't a problem.  `for word in wordStr` will iterate over the lines in "words.txt", because despite its name `wordStr` was an open file object.

Comment: Wow...yet another "I love Python!" moment!!  I had no idea it worked that way.

Comment: For posterity, I edited my answer to remove the false issue that DSM pointed out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(word == word[::-1] for word in wordStr.read().split())
```